# Mysql FullText, Match Against... and @ in search fields

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, match, against

```
select 
    count(distinct email_address)
from
    users
WHERE
    MATCH (email_address) AGAINST ('@rossi.it' );
```

Problem: the query search doesnt search for `'@rossi.it'` but only for `'rossi.it'`.

How I should modify the query in order to have the "@" included?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a backslash to escape the @ characters, like this:

```
WHERE
   MATCH (email_address) AGAINST ('\@rossi.it');
```

Does that solve it?